# chrome app angularjs+jquery console errors when processing remote html

Tags: jquery, angularjs, google-chrome

i have a chrome app and load a remote website (url is given by user input) via angularjs $http and parse content from the result with jquery. While that works, when i do

```
angular.element(data).find('.someclass h2.anotherclass a').each(function(i){ //do something }
```

i get a lot of errors like this displayed in the console:

```
Refused to load the image 'http://someurl.com/whatever_white.png' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data: chrome-extension-resource:".
```

How to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Try closing Chrome and restart with --disable-web-security argument. That's could help you as a workaround in development.
You can read about it here 
[Content Security](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy.html)

Comment: doesn't work here. still get these errors in console. Is it generally possible to load a remote site in a chrome-app and put the remote content (text, images) in some kind of new presentation layer? I cannot put URIs of the remote pages in manifest, because that should be a decision of the user what the remote URI is.